# can i pass array of properties on object.defineProperty()?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with properties/methods which I want to hide some of them

```
var Cons = function(str) {
  var ab = str.split(' '); 
  this.a= ab[0];
  this.b= ab[1];
  this.geta = function() {
    return this.a;
  };
  this.getb = function() {
    return this.b;
  };
}
```

on MDN syntax:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)
```

I hide some by using the code below, I want to pass an array of some keys on 'prop' is it possible?

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', {
  enumerable: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` only accepts a single key passed in as a string.
The easy solution would be to just iterate over the keys

```
var keys = ['prop1','prop2','prop3'];

keys.forEach(function(key) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        enumerable: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought of it :/